# "$PATH" being exported as literally "$PATH"

Tags: bash, path

So in a bash_config profile I have

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

But rather than appending the PATH it is setting it to:

```
[admin@vml1wk111 ~]$ echo $PATH
$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin:/home/admin/.local/bin:/home/admin/bin
```

With $PATH being the actual thing in the PATH rather than the variable it should be exporting.

What am I doing wrong?

I have had to do

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

everytime I login.

Comment: Run `bash -v` and see what's there.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be. You must have modified your `PATH` variable somewehere else, because your `/usr/local/sbin` comes after `$JAVA_HOME/bin` and not before. And after that is another `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin` with additional `/home/admin/.local/bin:/home/admin/bin`.

And there is no configuration file `bash_config` that is read on startup.

Check your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`.

**Edit:**

To debug, comment all lines in `/etc/profile.d/java.sh` (let every line begin with `#`) or move it somewhere else as backup and check if there are any other files inside the `/etc/profile.d` directory. Also check the system wide `/etc/profile`.

I still don't understand why `/bash_profile` should have been read (if it wasn't sourced by you in one of these files).
If it was read, then `$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin` expands to `/home/admin/.local/bin:/home/admin/bin` (the end part of your broken `PATH`) and `PATH` was already broken and set to

```
$PATH:\
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin:\
/usr/local/sbin:\
/usr/sbin:\
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin
```

Comment: I have these under `/etc/profile.d/java.sh`, sorry I don't know why I said that.  I never touched  `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` or`~/.profile` but they seem unnaffected.  I am at a loss as the only things getting exported are exactly what I did it that file. This is what I have being exported in my `/bash_profile` `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin`

Comment: So I figured out that it's being changed by a file other than my `etc/profile.d/java.sh` with my PATH now being `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin:/root/bin`

Comment: Solved!     So this is for a class lab. Many students where having trouble exporting the variables so the TAs went across all machines and did something under `/etc/environment` . I have no idea whether the other ones broke too. I managed to grep the line and used `stat` to see it was changed at a time I wasn't using it.